# docker - how to migrate mysql data from local to ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

In local environment, I am using docker-compose file to create multiple containers, including mysql container.
The data of mysql container is stored in `./db-data`.
There are 4 tables in the database, e.g. Table A,B,C,D.

In Development environment, I've created an ec2 instance and used same docker-compose file to create containers, while the mysql database is managed be Aws RDS.

I want to copy all the data of Table A and B from local to development environment, but I wonder how can I achieve this?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  test-db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true
      - MYSQL_USER=admin
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=12345
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
    volumes:
      - ./db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  test-web:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=local
      #- DEBUG=*
      - PORT=3030
    build: .
    command: >
      ./wait-for-db-redis.sh test-db npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    depends_on:
      - test-db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to migrate your data from  mysql on the instance to RDS mysql, probably `mysqldump` would be the easiest choice as explained in the AWS docs:

- [Importing data from a MySQL or MariaDB DB to a MySQL or MariaDB DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.SmallExisting.html)

> You can also import data from an existing MySQL or MariaDB database to a MySQL or MariaDB DB instance. You do so by copying the database with **mysqldump** and piping it directly into the MySQL or MariaDB DB instance.

There are other options to consider if basic `mysqldump` does not suit you, depending on your requirements. For example [migrating live database with minimal downtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html), or using `Percona XtraBackup software` as explained in [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html#MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Backup) as well, or even [AWS database migration service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marcin answer, if you are using MYSQLWorkbench you can do the following:

1. Run `SELECT * FROM <Your table name>;` in the table you want to extract the data
2. Click the `Export` button in `Result Grid`
3. Choose `SQL Insert statements` in Format
4. You can then get a list of SQL Insert statement.
   [image]